# Reverse journal editor search

Tags: publications

I was wondering if there is a tool that allows to search for journals where a given researcher is one of the editors.

Comment: I believe the simplest way to achieve something of that kind would be to look for the CV or research website of said researcher and look if they list their editorship responsibilities.

Comment: I do not think there are many researchers that are editor for more than 1 or 2 journals.

Comment: I guess if someone wants to advertise what journals they edit for, this will be visible on their web-page.

Comment: It's a fair question. Google Scholar does not currently support any search operator for this; I'm not sure about other portals. There is a more complex data scraping solution, but I imagine the easiest way is to search the individual's name, then click it and it should bring up a list of works they're associated with, although that would mix together ones where they are an author as well as an editor. Or use their CV.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid a certain editor, or is it something else?

Comment: @Buffy In this case I am asking in the abstract. In the past it occurred to me to use the opposite tactics: "Prof. X might like this sort of thing, is there an appropriate journal where they are also an editor".

Comment: Alternatively, you could just send them an abstract, ask if they'd like to see the whole paper and, after a bit of communication, asking for recommendations about where to send it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Try [Open Editors](https://openeditors.ooir.org/), a newly published dataset of ca. 480.000 editorial board positions across 6.000 scholarly journals at 17 academic publishers.

---

**OLD ANSWER**:

There are no open data* about editorial boards yet.

Thus, research articles that analyze the composition of journals' editorial boards unfortunately collect their data manually. For instance, [a paper](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0161357) in 2016 writes at p. 4:

> We began with a collection of 605 abbreviated titles of journals
> [...]. Crowdworkers from Amazon Mechanical Turk then expanded those
> abbreviations into full journal names and collected the individual
> editorships associated with each journal.

It has not gotten better since then.

However, there is a reason for optimism as ORCID allows users to list their editorial board positions. Unfortunately, ORCID remains underused; but perhaps in the future its API could offer a greater treasure trove regarding data on journals editors. (The same is true with WikiData).

* *Note: By "open data" I mean data that are, inter alia, interoperable, machine-readable, structured - see, for instance, [the explanation of "Open Data" at the European Data Portal](https://www.europeandataportal.eu/elearning/en/module1/#/id/co-01).*

Comment: "There are no open data about editorial boards yet." No, it's listed on journal websites.

Comment: Dear @AnonymousPhysicist, I edited my post to clarify what is understood as "open data".

Comment: That's clearer.